# handle vueJs events in regular javascript outside the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJs component on a regular web page. When it fires an event, I want the regular web page to respond. Is this possible?

Sites.vue is a single file component. It is instantiated in the middle of a regular web page

```
<sites @pmds="handlePmds"></sites>
```

From time to time, it emits an event with this:

```
this.$emit("pmds", pmds);
```

Back in the regular page, I want to handle the event like this:

```
    function handlePmds(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

But that doesn't work because `handlePmds` is not a VueJS function. So how do I catch that event?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the `pmds` data?

Comment: I want to use it to populate a jQuery autocomplete box. So the user picks a `site` using the `<site></site>` and when they do, it emits an event so that the jQuery autocomplete gets a list of label/value pairs.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more info to your question. Otherwise, it's hard to answer. As far as I know, you can't directly listen to an emitted Vue event, but you can set the data to an external variable. So, it really depends on how you're using it in this autocomplete box.

Comment: I could conceivably populate a hidden html input, but that wouldn't give me the notification to fill the autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a plain JS `CustomEvent` in one of the vueJS methods. The payload data goes in the second argument in a field called `detail`

```
methods: {
  sendPmds() {
    let event = new CustomEvent("pmds", { bubbles: true, detail: pmds });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

Then, in the main JS page, you handle the event like any other. In my case, I was using the data to populate a jQuery autocomplete field:

```
document.addEventListener("pmds", function(event) {
  if (event.detail?.length) {
    $("#pmd").autocomplete("option", "source", event.detail);
  }
```